# Can Bigby's Hand be healed?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, healing

Per the spell description, [*Bigby's Hand*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/bigbys-hand) is an object:

> The hand is **an object** that has AC 20 and hit points equal to your hit point maximum.

As an object, my instinct is to say that like other objects, *Bigby's Hand* could only be healed by a spell like [*Mending*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Mending) which explicitly heals objects:

> This spell repairs a single break or tear in an object you touch.

However, *Mending* has 2 obstacles. First is it has a casting time of 1 minute, the same as the duration of the *Bigby's Hand* spell. So functionally I don't know that the timing could work. Second, *Mending* continues to say:

> This spell can physically repair a magic item or construct, but **the spell can't restore magic to such an object.**

From RAI this wording might also prevent healing *Bigby's Hand* since it is a conjured magical object, the healing of which might be considered "restoring magic to the item".

I'm also not aware of any other spells used to heal objects other than Mending.

Moreover, the "conventional" healing spells seem to only apply to creatures, see e.g. [*Cure Wounds*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Cure%20Wounds), [*Heal*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Heal), [*Healing Word*](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Healing%20Word), etc.

So the question remains: is there a way to heal *Bigby's Hand*?

Comment: When I first read this question it was received as as "Can Bigby's Hand be Held' and I thought this might be a romantic RP question.  

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### There is no way to 'heal' *Bigby's Hand*

All of the healing or temp HP-granting spells only target creatures, and *Bigby's Hand* is not a creature.

Anything else would be homebrew, and I'd probably recommend against doing so. My experience with *Bigby's Hand* is that it is a **very** powerful spell. Healing it would increase its power level, and I wouldn't recommend adding more to this already powerful spell.

#### The Artificer's Steel Defender does provide a specific mechanic for repair

As user Weiramon pointed out in a comment on this answer, the [Battle Smith artificer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#BattleSmith)'s [Steel Defender](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/artificer#SteelDefender-1139436) does have a specific rule that applies to it that isn't available to other classes:

> ***Repair (3/Day).*** The magical mechanisms inside the defender restore 2d8 + PB hit points to itself or to one construct or object within 5 feet of it.

A Steel Defender is able to 'repair' an object, which *Bigby's Hand* is, so this is a possibility if your table allows artificers. I would be wary to expand this outside of this class, and I've got general concerns with the artificer in general, but there is a possible method for repairing the hand.

It's unclear to me if WotC **meant** for the defender to repair magical spell effects, but by the book, it works.

Comment: Tempted to agree re homebrewing something to heal the hand. More curious if I've either (1) misinterpreted the spells in my question, or (2) missed other spells that can heal objects.